# How to add dummies to Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a data_df that looks like:

```
   price vehicleType  yearOfRegistration    gearbox  powerPS  model  kilometer fuelType       brand notRepairedDamage  postalCode
0  18300       coupe                2011    manuell      190    NaN     125000   diesel        audi                ja       66954
1   9800         suv                2004  automatik      163  grand     125000   diesel        jeep               NaN       90480
2   1500  kleinwagen                2001    manuell       75   golf     150000   benzin  volkswagen              nein       91074
3   3600  kleinwagen                2008    manuell       69  fabia      90000   diesel       skoda              nein       60437
4    650   limousine                1995    manuell      102    3er     150000   benzin         bmw                ja       33775
```

Tried to convert classification columns (`vehicleType`) to dummies ("one hot encoding"):

```
columns = [ 'vehicleType' ] #, 'gearbox', 'model', 'fuelType', 'brand', 'notRepairedDamage' ]
for column in columns:
  dummies = pd.get_dummies(data_df[column], prefix=column)
  data_df.drop(columns=[column], inplace=True)
  data_df = data_df.add(dummies, axis='columns')
```

But the original data is missing:

```
  brand fuelType gearbox  kilometer model notRepairedDamage  ...  vehicleType_coupe  vehicleType_kleinwagen  vehicleType_kombi  vehicleType_limousine  vehicleType_suv  yearOfRegistration
0   NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN               NaN  ...                NaN                     NaN                NaN                    NaN              NaN                 NaN
1   NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN               NaN  ...                NaN                     NaN                NaN                    NaN              NaN                 NaN
2   NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN               NaN  ...                NaN                     NaN                NaN                    NaN              NaN                 NaN
3   NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN               NaN  ...                NaN                     NaN                NaN                    NaN              NaN                 NaN
4   NaN      NaN     NaN        NaN   NaN               NaN  ...                NaN                     NaN                NaN                    NaN              NaN                 NaN
```

So, how to replace a given column with the dummies?

Comment: Can you possibly provide a slightly more simplified example (with fewer columns—2 to 3) and provide your expected output for them?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
# Get one hot encoding of columns 'vehicleType'
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(data_df['vehicleType'])
# Drop column as it is now encoded
data_df = data_df.drop('vehicleType',axis = 1)
# Join the encoded df
data_df = data_df.join(one_hot)
data_df
```

Comment: `pd.get_dummies` can do it all. `pd.get_dummies(data_df, columns=['vehicleType'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')`

Comment: Previous comment should be the accepted answer

Comment: Agreed because the OP wanted to replace the former column.  The join would be necessary if one wants to preserve the former column.

Answer (score 11):

you can use a more compact way:

```
data_df = pd.get_dummies(data,columns=['vehicleType'],drop_first=True)
```

this line will drop your old column 'vehicleType', and automatically join the created columns to your dataset

Comment: I note the drop_first will create a base level by dropping one of the dummies, which may not have been requested.

Comment: Drop first removes one categorical value. [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)